# How to Set VotingResponses in Outlook via Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I am trying to issue approvals on mailbox items via Powershell but can't seem to find the right method to do so. Here is the code I have used thus far.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient('othermailbox@example.local')
$recipient.Resolve();
$sharedFolder = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($recipient, $olFolders::olFolderInBox)
$sharedFolder.Items
```

The member objects from $sharedFolder. Items contain string properties around VotingOptions and VotingResporse but I don't see a method to perform an approved vote. Any help is appreciated as there are hundreds of items I need to bulk approve. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the items, for each item read the VotingOptions property, call MailItem.Reply (returns the new item), set the VotingResponse property on the reply message, call Send.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up going with based on Dmitiry's input.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient('othermailbox@example.local')
$recipient.Resolve()
$sharedFolder = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($recipient, $olFolders::olFolderInBox)
$messages = $sharedFolder.Items | Where-Object { $_.subject -eq "Approval Required" }
foreach ($message in $messages)
{
    $reply = $message.Reply()
    $reply.VotingResponse = "Approve"
    $reply.Send()
}
```